# declare an empty array of size 100 in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing an application in php using codeigniter for a workflow process.

Now i need to declare an empty array of size 100 or 200 with null value default..whenever workflow executed anyways values get stored in to that array dynamically..

I am having a array in my view like

```
  if(isset($value)){

 foreach ($value as $row) {

 $wer[] = $row;

 }
 }
```

Now whenever workflow runs automatically values get stored in view using `form_dropdown('perfpmself_1',$rate,$wer[0],'class="self"');`
from the above format i use to load all values from $wer[0] to $wer[50]. All values will displayed properly...but if there is no values in database to load it to an array..it is throwing an error like

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: wer

Filename: views/performancepm.php
```

Can anyone suggests a solution for this to overcome this error on my view screen??

Please help..thanks in advance

Comment: You're PHP is old. You need to declare $wer first. $wer = array(); outside of the foreach.

Comment: hi steven..i forgot to post that array declaration code..i declared it before isset.. but of no use :(

Comment: thanx for ur reply steven..i wrote an sql query to fill all column values with 0 as default..so my $wer[] is stored with 0 in default..thanx for ur instant reply :)

Comment: hi John Conde,mkaatman and Steven..can you please tell me how to add required field to form_dropdown instead of keeping in rules=>'required'. Looking of ur replies

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize `$wer` before trying to assign a value to it:

```
if(isset($value)){
    $wer = array();
    foreach ($value as $row) {
        $wer[] = $row;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Actually, he probably needs to assign it before the isset. I bet he references it regardless of $value.

Comment: Probably. I don't have much to go on so I just declared it where I know it's gonna be used.

Comment: hi..thanks for ur prompt replies..neither before isset or after isset declaring an array didnt solve my prob.. :(. instead i wrote an sql query to fill all column values with default 0..which helped in throwing 0 value defaultly..thanks for ur suggestions :)

Comment: hi John Conde,mkaatman and Steven..can you please tell me how to add required field to form_dropdown instead of keeping in rules=>'required'. Looking of ur replies...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$options = array_fill_keys(range(0,99),null);
echo form_dropdown('perfpmself_1', $options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define wer globally. Also I'd use array_push, but thats just me. Keep it simple:

```
$wer = array();

 if(isset($value)){

     foreach ($value as $row) {

         array_push($wer, $row);

     }
 }

if(empty($wer)){
    //wer has values
}else{
    // wer is not empty
}
```

In regards to your comments, as far as I know there is only one way to enforce the required field specifically in the codeIgniter framework:

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
```

From the [CodeIgniter Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrules)

Otherwise youll have to enforce it using JavaScript or in your own PHP code to see if is an empty field:

```
if (isset($_GET['username'])){
//username isnt blank
}else{
//username is blank
}
```